# Use Zod to validate schema with Firestore DocumentReferences in it (with defaults)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, zod

I'm trying to use Zod to get some type sanity while using Firebase Firestore (and this is specific to Firestore). Let's say I have a type like this:

```js
export type FooType = {
    id: string;
    relatedDocument: DocumentReference;
    otherRelatedDocument: DocumentReference;
};
```

And I want to validate it with a Zod schema, like this one:

```js
export const fooTypeSchema = z.object({
    id: z.string(),
    relatedDocument: ???,
    otherRelatedDocument: ???,
});
```

If all I want to do is *validate*, it looks like I can kinda do it structurally with something like this:

```js
const dataConverterSchema = z.object({
  fromFirestore: z.function(),
  toFirestore: z.function(),
});

const docRefDocDataSchema =
  z.object({
    constructor: z.function(),
    converter: z.union([dataConverterSchema, z.null()]),
    firestore: z.object({ constructor }),
    id: z.string(),
    parent: z.object({ constructor }),
    path: z.string(),
    type: z.literal('document'),
    withConverter: z.function(),
  });
```

...but now say I want to do something like this:

```js
export const fooTypeSchema = z.object({
    id: z.string(),
    relatedDocument: docRefDocDataSchema.default(() => doc(TABLE_NAME, DOC_ID)),
    otherRelatedDocument: docRefDocDataSchema.default(() => doc(TABLE_NAME, DOC_ID)),
});
```

This does not work. I suspect there are a number of things in play, but the first error message in the chain is about how the constructor of `DocumentReference<DocumentData>` is private (and indeed, `doc()` is the factory function for it).

The ultimate goal here is to be able to do: `const newObj = fooTypeSchema.parse({id: "Foo"});` and get a valid object back, populated with default created docRefs. I've seen a number of Zod-based libraries that claim to handle docRefs (Fireschema and Firesword) that claim to support docRefs, but they don't seem to handle defaults, only validation.

Overall, Zod seems really great at dealing with primitive types, but when I bring classes (not to mention classes with fancy stuff like private constructors) it seems to get difficult.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

My initial thought was to use [`z.instanceof`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#instanceof) to parse the document reference but that runs into the same "private constructor" issue that you were seeing with your schema.

Instead, I would suggest working around that by first parsing a very simple value, and then using a type guard with [`refine`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#refine), for example:

```js
const docRefDocDataSchema = z.object({}).refine(
  (x: object): x is DocumentReference => x instanceof DocumentReference,
);
```

Which you can use in your original schema as is.

Comment: This seems to satisfy the desired ability to create default objects with no problem, but it fails at validating (valid) objects that come from the database. Runtime error says: Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'va', but it was: a custom Object object. I tried various permutations of z.object({}) and my structural schema, but couldn't get any of them to work for both use cases. :/

Comment: Interesting. If it was a validation error from zod I would expect it to throw a `ZodError` rather than a FirebaseError. It’s a bit difficult to try and recreate the problem without running a real fire base instance to test against, but maybe you could share the code from the promise?

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like the following?

```
z.custom<DocumentReference>(
    (val) => {
        return val instanceof DocumentReference;
    },
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).